# how to disable both layout and renderer on entire Zend Framework application

Tags: zend-framework, layout, renderer

I know how to disable them on specific controller:

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
```

And I know how to disable renderer in the bootstrap:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->setParam('noViewRenderer', true);
```

Is there any chance to disable layout in the bootstrap?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$l = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
$l->disableLayout();
```

That will disable your layout. `setNoRender` will disable all output, which one do you want? (In your post you state layout)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it seems to be wrong one. Fatal error: Call to a member function disableLayout() on a non-object. I'm using ZendFramework-1.11.0.

Comment: Make sure you are calling it after you have initialised your layout; usually with Zend_Layout::startMvc

Answer (score 1):

IFAIK the layout is disabled by default, until you enable layout resource in `application.ini`, so disable it there.